# Loop through dynamic errors on a form field in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Thanks all - here is my issue:

I have a form field in angular - using all the form constructs, and the errors come back as an unknown array of them from the database. There seems to be no possible way to iterate through the errors and play them back...

for example - i'm doing a ton of these:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(_data.formId).hasError('ClientAuthorizationError')">
    {{ form.get(_data.formId).getError('ClientAuthorizationError') }}
  </mat-error>
```

What I want to do is create the mat-error array based on the data coming back - this makes it rigid the way I have it. I've heard - you can't do this currently with a mat-form-field

Any suggestions before I scream at the angular team?

Love!

Comment: There seems to be no way to nest an ng-template inside a form field - the whole changeStrategy would have to change

Comment: Can you not use `form.get(_data.formId).errors`?

Comment: no - it doesn't know about them when you loop through

Comment: it's like the loop stops it from knowing about what's happening in the errors

Comment: so it just doesn't show the error messages